# Pandas: merge dataframes without creating new columns inside a for operation

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to enrich a dataframe with data collected from an API.
So, I'm going like this:

```
for i in df.index:
    if pd.isnull(df.cnpj[i]) == True:
        pass
    else:
        k=get_financials_hnwi(df.cnpj[i]) # this is my API requesting function, working fine
        df=df.merge(k,on=["cnpj"],how="left") # here is my problem <-------------------------------
```

Since I'm running that merge in a for sentence, it is showing up suffixes (_x, _y). So I found this alternative here:

[Pandas: merge dataframes without creating new columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41262379/pandas-merge-dataframes-without-creating-new-columns)

```
for i in df.index:
     if pd.isnull(df.cnpj[i]) == True:
        pass
    else:
        k=get_financials_hnwi(df.cnpj[i]) # this is my requesting function, working fine
        val = np.intersect1d(df.cnpj, k.cnpj)
        df_temp = pd.concat([df,k], ignore_index=True)
        df=df_temp[df_temp.cnpj.isin(val)]
```

However it creates a new df, killing the original index and not allowing this line to run `if pd.isnull(df.cnpj[i]) == True:`.

Is there a nice way to run a merge/join/concat inside a for operation without creating new columns with _x and _y? Or there is a way to mix _x and _y columns afterall getting rid of it and condensing it in a single column? I just want a single column with all of it

**Sample data and reproducible code**

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'cnpj':[12,32,54,65],'co_name':['Johns Market','T Bone Gril','Superstore','XYZ Tech']})

#first API request:

k=pd.DataFrame({'cnpj':[12],'average_revenues':[687],'years':['2019,2018,2017']})
df=df.merge(k,on="cnpj", how='left')

#second API request:
k=pd.DataFrame({'cnpj':[32],'average_revenues':[456],'years':['2019,2017']})
df=df.merge(k,on="cnpj", how='left')

#third API request:
k=pd.DataFrame({'cnpj':[53],'average_revenues':[None],'years':[None]})
df=df.merge(k,on="cnpj", how='left')

#fourth API request:
k=pd.DataFrame({'cnpj':[65],'average_revenues':[4142],'years':['2019,2018,2015,2013,2012']})
df=df.merge(k,on="cnpj", how='left')

print(df)
```

Result:

```
   cnpj       co_name average_revenues_x         years_x  average_revenues_y  \
0    12  Johns Market              687.0  2019,2018,2017                 NaN   
1    32   T Bone Gril                NaN             NaN               456.0   
2    54    Superstore                NaN             NaN                 NaN   
3    65      XYZ Tech                NaN             NaN                 NaN   

     years_y average_revenues_x years_x  average_revenues_y  \
0        NaN               None    None                 NaN   
1  2019,2017               None    None                 NaN   
2        NaN               None    None                 NaN   
3        NaN               None    None              4142.0   

                    years_y  
0                       NaN  
1                       NaN  
2                       NaN  
3  2019,2018,2015,2013,2012
```

Desired result:

```
   cnpj       co_name   average_revenues                     years
0    12  Johns Market              687.0            2019,2018,2017                 
1    32   T Bone Gril              456.0                 2019,2017               
2    54    Superstore               None                      None        
3    65      XYZ Tech             4142.0  2019,2018,2015,2013,2012
```

Comment: please add some sample data and expected output that clearly illustrates your problem. From reading your problem, I would hold the values in dictionaries then map them into your target dataframes.

Comment: alright, I will put some sample data

Comment: @Datanovice since I'm calling an API it is quite tricky to samplify the data. Does it look ok or you would suggest a different way to sample it?

Answer (score 1):

as your joining on a single column and mapping values we can take advantage of the `cnpj` column and set it to the index, we can then use `combine_first` or `update` or `map` to add your values into your dataframe.

assuming `k` will look like this. If not just update the function to return a dictionary that you can use `map` with.

```
   cnpj  average_revenues           years
0    12               687  2019,2018,2017
```

---

lets hold this in a tidy function.

```
def update_api_call(dataframe,api_call):
    
    if dataframe.index.name == 'cnpj':
        pass
    else:
        dataframe = dataframe.set_index('cnpj')
    
    return dataframe.combine_first(
                                    api_call.set_index('cnpj')
                                   )
```

assuming your variable `k`s are numbered 1-4 for our test.

```
df1 = update_api_call(df,k1)

print(df1)

      average_revenues       co_name           years
cnpj                                                
12               687.0  Johns Market  2019,2018,2017
32                 NaN   T Bone Gril             NaN
54                 NaN    Superstore             NaN
65                 NaN      XYZ Tech             NaN


df2 = update_api_call(df1,k2)

print(df2)

      average_revenues       co_name           years
cnpj                                                
12               687.0  Johns Market  2019,2018,2017
32               456.0   T Bone Gril       2019,2017
54                 NaN    Superstore             NaN
65                 NaN      XYZ Tech             NaN
```

---

```
print(df4)
      average_revenues       co_name                     years
cnpj                                                          
12               687.0  Johns Market            2019,2018,2017
32               456.0   T Bone Gril                 2019,2017
53                 NaN           NaN                       NaN
54                 NaN    Superstore                       NaN
65              4142.0      XYZ Tech  2019,2018,2015,2013,2012
```